# Is my proof of the fact that continuous partials imply differentiability, absolutely rigorous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, normed-spaces, partial-derivative

> **Theorem:** Let $V$, $W$ be finite-dimensional normed linear spaces and $W$ be over $\mathbb R$. ($V$ can possibly be over $\mathbb C$.) Let $(e_1, \ldots, e_n)$ and $(\tilde e_1,\ldots, \tilde e_m)$ be bases for $V$ and $W$. Let $F\colon \Omega\to W$ where $\Omega$ is open in $V$ such that each of the $\partial_i f_j$'s (see the note at the end) exist throughout $\Omega$ and are continuous at $c\in\Omega$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $c$.

***My proof:***

Since differentiability (and the partials) are independent of the norms on either of the spaces, we choose to work with $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$ norms so that, for instance, $\lVert \sum_i x_i e_i\rVert = \sum_i |x_i|$ in $V$. Similarly in $W$.

Let $\delta > 0$ such that $B_\delta(c)\subseteq\Omega$ and let $h\in B_\delta(0)\setminus\{0\}$. Now, define a sequence $x^{(0)}, \ldots, x^{(n)}\in V$ by $x^{(0)} := c$ and $x^{(k+1)} := x^{(k)} + h_{k + 1} e_{k + 1}$ $(h_k$'s are components of $h$). Since we are considering $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$ norm, each $x^{(k)}\in B_\delta(c)$. Now,
$$
f(c + h) - f(c) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \bigl(f(x^{(k)}) - f(x^{(k-1)})\bigr).\tag{1}
$$
Fix a $1\le k\le n$. Now there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for each $t\in(-\epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)$, we have $x^{(k-1)} + t h_k e_k\in B_\delta(c)$. Hence we can define $g\colon (-\epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)\to V$ by $t\mapsto f(x^{(k-1)} + th_k e_k)$. Now, decomposing $g$ in basis $(\tilde e_1, \ldots, \tilde e_m)$, we get $g_j$'s on $(-\epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)\to \mathbb R$ and now we are in a position to apply MVT. Before that we show that each $g_j$ is differentiable:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\xi\to 0}\frac{g_j(t + \xi) - g_j(t)}{\xi}
& = \lim_{\xi\to 0}\frac{f_j(v + \xi h e_k) - f_j(v)}{\xi}\\
& = h\; \partial_k f_j(v)
\end{align*}
$$
where $v := x^{(k-1)} + th_k e_k$.

Now, applying MVT on the interval $[0, 1]$, we get a $\theta\in (0, 1)$ such that
$$
\begin{align*}
g_j(1) - g_j(0) & = g'_j(\theta)\\
& = h\; \partial_k f_j(x^{(k-1)} + \theta h_k e_k). \tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$
Now using the continuity of the partials, we can assume w.l.o.g. that $\delta$ is small enough so that $|\partial_k f_j(c + h) - \partial_k f_j(c)|\le \epsilon/m$ for all $k$, $j$. Since $x^{(k - 1)} + \theta h e_k\in B_\delta(c)$ (easy), (2) yields
$$
| g_j(1) - g_j(0) - h_k \; \partial_k f_j(c) |\le |h_k| \epsilon/m
$$
for all $j$.

Summing the $g_i$'s to yield $g$ and noting that $g(1) - g(0) = f(x^{(k)}) - f(x^{(k-1)})$, we get
$$
\Big\lVert f(x^{(k)}) - f(x^{(k-1)}) - \sum_{j = 1}^m h_k\; \partial_k f_j(c)\; \tilde e_j \Big\rVert\le |h_k|\epsilon.
$$

Now using (1) and triangle inequality, we get
$$
\Big\lVert f(x) - f(c) - \sum_{j = 1}^m\sum_{k = 1}^n h_k\; \partial_k f_j(c)\; \tilde e_j \Big\rVert \le\epsilon\lVert h\rVert
$$
and we conclude by noting that the double sum is (the obviously given linear map $V\to W$) acting on $h$.

---

By $\partial_i f_j(c)$, I mean the following limit:
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f_j(c + t e_i) - f_j(c)}{t}
$$

$f_j$'s on $\Omega\to\mathbb R$ are components of $f\colon\Omega\to W$ in $W$'s basis.